# Error in declaring global variable in html document and using it

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have defined a global variable in `html` document

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var total;
</script>
```

but when I want to use it, an error occured that this variable can not be used in this context.

use

```
<td style="background-color: #CCCCCC; color: #000000; border:1px solid #FFFFFF">@Html.Raw(total)</td>
```

Comment: its a js variable not c#

Comment: You can not use this variable, as this is JAVASCRIPT variable.... and you're trying to use in C# context

Comment: I have to use that variable first inside the loop to get increment and the outside the loop pring on the page.

Comment: @DotNetIsMyPower I have to use in C# context. how could I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<script>

var total;

document.write('<td id="yourtabledata" style="background-color: #CCCCCC; color: #000000; border:1px solid #FFFFFF">'+total+'</td>');

</script>
```

Comment: For example I have tried to do like this 

    <script>
    var total = 0;
    @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
        var total =   item.t_Gesamtzeit_s_msg;
     }
    </script>

but `total`insdie the loop is not recognized